# Localhost frontpage - index.php showing "This webpage is not available" - Admin works

Tags: magento-1.9, localhost

Im trying to setup my LIVE Magento repo on localhost (WAMP) and simply **can't get the website itself to work. Admin works.** Currently I can conclude the following:

1. Requesting: http://127.0.0.1/mywebsitealias/index.php - the frontpage - does not work, shows "This webpage is not available"
2. Requesting: http://127.0.0.1/mywebsitealias/test.html - works
3. Requesting: http://127.0.0.1/mywebsitealias/index.php/admin/ - works, I can login and see all of my database imported data. Products, users, sales - everything is there.

*Symptons noted when I request the frontpage:*

4. Loading spinner "thinks" a lot - the frontpage doesn't give an
   instant response (so seems it's actually "connecting" to something)
5. Nothing appears in the console.log
6. Nothing / no errors appear in var/log or var/report

**Any suggestions on what could be causing this?**

*What I tried - so far:*

7. Ran search and replace DB path values from LIVE site to locahost path via:
   https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/
8. Read several places using 127.0.0.1/ rather than localhost was
   recommend, so ended up using that
9. Tried adding `set_time_limit(1800);` in the start of index.php
10. In php.ini: set - `max_execution_time = 1800`
11. In php.ini: set - `max_input_vars = 1800`
12. In php.ini: set - `memory_limit = 512M`
13. In php.ini: set - `mysql.connect_timeout = -1`
14. Double checkhed In DB Table: `core_config_data` > `web/unsecure/base_url` +
    `web/secure/base_url` checked that path is set to:
        http://127.0.0.1/mywebsitealias/
15. Deleted possible cache + sessions files in-between all
16. In Backend > Index Management > Tried to re-index all
17. In WAMP > Apache modules > Enabled `filter_module`,
     `header_module`, `rewrite_module`

I have a lot Wordpress / custom projects running on localhost with alias, so WAMP itself would be fully functional and working.

Comment: check the apache log or php log because I think that is something related to "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted", and if you are using a custom theme change to default Magento's theme.

Comment: Maybe the live site is using something like memcached, redis or varnish in any kind? For example session caching is set to memcached or redis but you don't have installed it? Or you have a Magento2 installation but your mysql version is too low? Something with Php version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I think you should go to Admin and **System->Configuration->general->Web->Default Pages** and select **CMS Home Page** to your page
Hope you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128913/magento-homepage-keeps-on-redirecting-to-a-404-page)
worked for me. Perhaps you have a similar issue going on.

In my case, there was an empty `request_path` in the `core_url_rewrite` table of the Magento database. Once I deleted the entry with the empty `request_path` field, my home page was accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have `maintenance.flag` file in your Magento root.
If you have, just remove.

Answer (score 0):

please check after removing your .htaccess file on magento root